# Find common elements in 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, intersection

If I have two (or more) 2D arrays, how can I get only common elements between the arrays given a row number. For example, I have arrays in the format:

```
time, position, velocity, acceleration
```

I want to get the two arrays to only have the same time elements, so row 0. I can use

```
np.intersect1d(array1[:, 0], array2[:, 0])
```

which gives all the common times, but I want to either extract all matching rows/columns from array1/2 or remove non common time elements. In the end
`array1` and `array2` will have the exact same dimensions so I could go:

```
pos_difference = array1[:, 1] - array2[:, 1]
```

The arrays could be different sizes, so for example:

```
array1 = [[1, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0], [3, 120.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
array2 = [[1, 101.0, 0.0, 0.0], [3, 119, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

And I want to extract only common time elements so array1 and array2 will only contain when Time=1, and Time=3, since those are the common time elements. Then I can go:

```
pos_difference = array1[:, 1] - array2[:, 1]
```

and this will be the position differences between the two arrays at the same time:

```
# First row will be when time=1 and second row will be when time=3
pos_difference = [[0, -1, 0.0, 0.0], [0, 1, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: It would help if you include a minimal example `array1` and `array2` plus the expected result. I think I know what you need but I'm not sure because I can't compare it to your actual arrays and expectation.

Comment: @MSeifert I gave a small example, hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: Thank you. That's clear! One further question though: Are the times in each array unique and sorted?

Comment: Take a look at Pandas library, it looks like a good use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have these arrays:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[1, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0], [3, 120.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
array2 = np.array([[1, 101.0, 0.0, 0.0], [3, 119, 0.0, 0.0]])
```

As you said you can use `np.intersect1d` to get the intersection, the only thing remaining is to index the arrays:

```
intersect = np.intersect1d(array1[:, 0], array2[:, 0])

array1_matches = array1[np.any(array1[:, 0] == intersect[:, None], axis=0)]
array2_matches = array2[np.any(array2[:, 0] == intersect[:, None], axis=0)]
```

And then you can subtract them:

```
>>> array1_matches - array2_matches
array([[ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

This assumes that your times are unique and sorted. In case they are unsorted you could sort them before:

```
>>> array1 = array1[np.argsort(array1[:, 0])]
>>> array2 = array2[np.argsort(array2[:, 0])]
```

In case the times are not-unique I have no idea how you want to handle that, so I can't advise you there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `numpy.in1d`.

```
array1 = array1[np.in1d(array1[:,0], array2[:,0]), assume_unique=True]
array2 = array2[np.in1d(array2[:,0], array1[:,0]), assume_unique=True]
```

Or if you don't want to change your originals:

```
array3 = array1[np.in1d(array1[:,0], array2[:,0]), assume_unique=True]
array4 = array2[np.in1d(array2[:,0], array3[:,0]), assume_unique=True]
```

Notice in both cases I'm using the reduced array as the target of the second `in1d` to reduce search time.  If you want to optimize even more you can wrap it in an `if` statement to assure the smaller array is the target of the first `in1d`.

Then just do `array3-array4`

```
def common_subtract(a1, a2, i = 0, unique = True):
    a1, a2 = np.array(a1), np.array(a2)
    if a1.shape[0] > a2.shape[0]:  
        a1 = a1[np.in1d(a1[:, i], a2[:, i], assume_unique = unique)]
        a2 = a2[np.in1d(a2[:, i], a1[:, i], assume_unique = unique)]
    else:
        a2 = a2[np.in1d(a2[:, i], a1[:, i], assume_unique = unique)]
        a1 = a1[np.in1d(a1[:, i], a2[:, i], assume_unique = unique)]
    return a1 - a2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found using intersect1d more clearer way to find common elements in 2D numpy array. In this case `recent_books` and `coding_books` have been defined.

```
start = time.time()
recent_coding_books = np.intersect1d([recent_books], [coding_books]) 
print(len(recent_coding_books))
print('Duration: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```